# Before css chrome border radius - crop bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem in chrome. I set a before statement to my class `.button` to make an animation on hover, but the end of the `::before` is crop :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s558b.gif

And the code source :

```css
body {
  background:#000;  
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 24px 14px 24px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0282d1;
  border-radius: 999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

button {
  border:0; 
  background:none;
  color:#fff;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #02AFF1, #0057A3);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: scale3d(1, 2, 1);
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in, opacity 300ms ease-in;
  border-radius: 999px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover::before {
  transform: scale3d(9, 9, 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">ACCUEIL</button>
```

I can't find solution on google.
It's works on safari & firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see the crop..

Comment: Looks good to me!  ;)

Comment: It's working for me, 
I have **chrome Version 48.0.2564.116**

Comment: [**chrome 49**](http://i.gyazo.com/506f5384dcba950613c7610fd59bde28.gif)

Comment: probably you have increased your window with a browser zoom. Try Ctrl / Cmd + 0?

Comment: I don't know what happen today but it's works... thank you.